# Can pandas select some data or all data specific column and average every 5 rows by using pandas with Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I would like to calculate average or std value every 5 rows in specific column and **select data (first or last or all or some data that I choose)** from another column by using pandas with python 2.7

This is my dataframe (example) :

```
>>df
       DateTime     Product     Location       Value       Place
0    12-07-2018           A           S1       1.313       601
1    12-07-2018           B           S1       3.089       601/14
2    12-07-2018           C           S1       1.890       601
3    12-07-2018           D           S1       3.136       601
4**  12-07-2018           E           S1       3.258       601/15
5    13-07-2018           F           S1       3.113       601
6    13-07-2018           G           S1       2.651       601/12
7    13-07-2018           H           S1       2.135       601
8    13-07-2018           I           S1       1.555       602
9**  14-07-2018           J           S1       2.009       602
10   14-07-2018           K           S1       1.757       602
11   14-07-2018           L           S1       1.808       602/11
12   14-07-2018           M           S1       1.511       603/10
13   15-07-2018           N           S1       2.265       603
14** 15-07-2018           O           S1       2.356       603
15   15-07-2018           P           S1       2.950       603/09
16   15-07-2018           Q           S1       3.300       603/09
```

Now I can average value every 5 rows and select data from "DateTime","Place" column (first or last) by use this code(**example. average and select last**) :

```
new_df = df[:(len(df)//5)*5].groupby(df[:(len(df)//5)*5].index // 5).agg({'DateTime':'last', 'Value':'mean', 'Place':'last'})
```

This is result of average value every 5 rows and select last data (**example. average and select last**) :

```
>> new_df
     DateTime       Value     Place
0  12-07-2018      2.5372     601/15
1  14-07-2018      2.2926     602
2  15-07-2018      1.9394     603
```

If I want result same this (average, select last and all):

```
>> new_df
     DateTime   Product      Value      Place
0  12-07-2018   A,B,C,D,E    2.5372     601, 601/14, 601, 601, 601/15
1  14-07-2018   F,G,H,I,J    2.2926     601, 601/12, 601, 602, 602 
2  15-07-2018   K,L,M,N,O    1.9394     602, 602, 602/11, 603/10, 603
```

and (average, select some data)

```
>> new_df
     DateTime   Product      Value      Place
0  12-07-2018   A,C,E        2.5372     601, 601/14, 601
1  14-07-2018   F,G          2.2926     601, 601/12
2  15-07-2018   L,M,N,O      1.9394     602/11
```

Can pandas do this ???

**Note : I add ** for easy to observe at every 5 rows.**

Comment: If seelct only some values, average is not changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.join` in aggregate dictionary:

```
d = {'DateTime':'last', 'Value':'mean', 'Place':', '.join, 'Product':', '.join}
new_df = df[:(len(df)//5)*5].groupby(df[:(len(df)//5)*5].index // 5).agg(d)
print (new_df)
    DateTime   Value                          Place        Product
0 2018-12-07  2.5372  601, 601/14, 601, 601, 601/15  A, B, C, D, E
1 2018-07-14  2.2926     601, 601/12, 601, 602, 602  F, G, H, I, J
2 2018-07-15  1.9394  602, 602/11, 603/10, 603, 603  K, L, M, N, O
```

But if want filtering in aggregate function:

```
def f(x):
    a = x['DateTime'].iloc[-1]
    b = x['Value'].mean()

    x = x[x['Product'].isin(['A','C','E','F','G','L','M','N', 'O'])]
    c = ', '.join(x['Place'])
    d = ', '.join(x['Product'])
    return pd.Series([a,b,c,d], index=['DateTime','Value','Place','Product'])

new_df = df[:(len(df)//5)*5].groupby(df[:(len(df)//5)*5].index // 5).apply(f)
print (new_df)
    DateTime   Value                     Place     Product
0 2018-12-07  2.5372          601, 601, 601/15     A, C, E
1 2018-07-14  2.2926               601, 601/12        F, G
2 2018-07-15  1.9394  602/11, 603/10, 603, 603  L, M, N, O
```

Comment: @ jezrael Thank you very much for your help. You alway helped me when I had a problem. I really appreciate that.

Comment: If dataframe have many rows (about 100 200 ++) it can't use .agg(d) . Why it happen?

Comment: @kanpiseksasuk - Why you cannot use? It raise error?

Comment: @kanpiseksasuk - What kind of error? Column `F` is `Product` column?

Comment: @ jezrael Column **F** is **Place** column.  Now has not problem. I do not know why the error is not raise but at past problem alert about variable to be aggregate doesn't create. I decided to solve the problem at that time to select last of **Place** column  --->>  'Place' : 'last' then the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Reason of error maybe because the information in my "Place" column is like this.